# Examples of partial functions in which the domain is not known?

Tags: functions, computer-science, computability

I was reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function), it mentions about a kind of function in which the *exact domain* is not known. The only example given is [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function#Bottom_type) - and I'm not really sure I understood it. I got curious about it:

- What are examples of these functions? (beyond the one I suggested as an example)
- What would be needed to know their *exact domain*?

I got curious about it because I'm an undergraduate student, every function I've seen had a known domain. The idea of not having a domain is completely alien to me. Notice that It's notvery clear what *exact domain* is, I have in mind only the discrepancy of domain/image.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the partial function which takes as input a Turing machine and returns as output its [halting time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) if it has one. The exact domain of this function, namely the set of Turing machines which have halting times, is in a pretty strong sense impossible to know because the halting problem is undecidable.

Answer (score 3):

The [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) provides a nice example:

$$
f(n) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ for } n = 1, \\
f(n/2) & \text{ for } n \text{ even}, \\
f(3n+1) & \text{ for } n \text{ odd},
\end{cases}
$$

for any positive $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The conjecture is (equivalent to) that the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$, but we don't know it. However, if it is true, then $f \equiv (n \mapsto 1)$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 2):

You can build such a function whenever you have a function $f$ whose zeros are unknown. For example, set $$
  f(z) = \frac{1}{\zeta(z)}
$$
where $\zeta(z)$ is the Riemann zeta function. It is conjectured, but not proven, that for all zeros of $\zeta(z)$, either $z = -2n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (these are called the trivial zeros) or $\textrm{Re} z = \frac{1}{2}$ (this is what is unknown). It has been proved that all non-trivial zeros lie in the strip $0 < \textrm{Re} z < 1$, so we currently *know* that the domain of $f$ is at least $$
  \textrm{dom } f = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid -\tfrac{1}{2}z \notin \mathbb{N} \textrm{ and } \textrm{Re } z \notin (0,1)\} \text{.}
$$
If the riemann hypothesis turns out to be true, the domain can be enlarged to $$
  \textrm{dom } f = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid -\tfrac{1}{2}z \notin \mathbb{N} \textrm{ and } \textrm{Re } z \neq \tfrac{1}{2}\} \text{.}
$$

Answer (score -2):

Suppose $f\subset A\times B$. Then $f$ is a partial function if and only if for all $x\in A$ and all $y_1,y_2\in B$, if $(x,y_1)\in f$ and $(x,y_2)\in f$ then $y_1=y_2$. (Unlike others, this definition does not specify a domain for $f$. Implicitly, the domain is some subset of $A$.)

You can still use the functional notation $f(x)=y$, but you cannot assume that $f(x)$ is defined for every $x\in A$.

Examples:

$f= \{(2,9), (5, 7)\}\subset N^2$ is a partial function on $N$ where $f(2)=9$ and $f(5)=7$.

$g= \{(2,9), (2, 7)\}\subset N^2$ is *not* a partial function on $N$ since $2$ is mapped to *different* values.

$h= \{(9,2), (7,2)\}\subset N^2$ *is* a partial function on $N$  even though different elements of $N$ are mapped to the *same* value, where $h(9)=2$ and $h(7)=2$.

Comment: I don't see how this answers any part of the question.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I provide an alternative definition of a partial function that makes no mention of a domain. I find it more useful than the usual definition (e.g. at Wikipedia)  that explicitly mentions a domain. I also give some examples.

Comment: I still don't see how this answers any part of the question. The question is about examples of partial functions whose exact domains aren't known.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Only the OP can say for sure if this answers her question or not, but it seemed to me that she had an incomplete understanding of what a partial function is. She did not seem to understand that, to prove that a relation is a partial function, you do not need to specify its domain.